# How to ingest json object that contains array in S3 to AWS Opensearch in a pipeline

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pipeline, opensearch

No object was injested and in cloudwatch log found error:
`2024-03-12T00:21:29.627 [Thread-11] ERROR org.opensearch.dataprepper.plugins.source.s3.S3ObjectWorker - Error reading from S3 object: s3ObjectReference=[bucketName=test2-8964, key=5a34c11a21ab22621b026ed00936aa425a2d75345585ddc06b380afd87ae7563.json]. Cannot construct instance of` java.util.LinkedHashMap `(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('dummystring') at [Source: (org.opensearch.dataprepper.plugins.source.s3.S3InputStream); line: 3, column: 9]`

my pipeline configuration:

````yaml
version: "2"
test-pipeline:
  source:
    s3:
      codec:
        json:
      compression: "none"
      aws:
        region: "us-west-1"
        sts_role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::896497961826:role/test-pipeline"
      acknowledgments: true
      scan:
        scheduling:
          interval: PT30S
        buckets:
          - bucket:
              name: test2-8964
      delete_s3_objects_on_read: false
  processor:
    - date:
        destination: "@timestamp"
        from_time_received: true
  sink:
    - opensearch:
        hosts: ["https://search-test-6zryuwp5gchu72mzgpscbjx4qu.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
        index: "test-pipeline"
        aws:
          sts_role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::896497961826:role/test-pipeline"
          region: "us-west-1"
        dlq:
          s3:
            bucket: "test2-8964"
            region: "us-west-1"
            sts_role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::896497961826:role/test-pipeline"```
````

each file in S3 is a single document, example object in S3:

```json
{
    "array": [
        "dummystring"
    ]
}
```

I have tried to add:

```yaml
  processor:
    - parse_json:
```

but didn't help.

How to set the pipeline properly?